# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting for expiration dates

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I need help!

I need to create conditional formatting for expiration dates:

Cells should stay green

Cells should turn yellow when 1 month of exp. date

Cells should turn red once expired

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

- green: **Date is after exact date** **`=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,DAY(TODAY()))`**
- yellow: **Is between** **`=TODAY()`** **`=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,DAY(TODAY()))`**
- red: **Less than** **`=TODAY()`**

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wvbvFCCvgGt8LRGEm4-PE4J1nIpL-mxQZ1DKGq0jPWs/edit#gid=0)**